# Playing a stream of video data using QTKit on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, video, video-streaming, qtkit

I've been playing with QTKit for a couple of days and I'm successfully able to record video data to a file from the camera using a `QTCaptureSession` and `QTCaptureDeviceInput` etc.

However what I want to do is send the data to another location, either over the network or to a different object within the same app (it doesn't matter) and then play the video data as if it were a stream.

I have a `QTCaptureMovieFileOutput` and I am passing `nil` as the file URL so that it doesn't actually record the data to the file (I'm only interested in the data contained in the `QTSampleBuffer` that is available via the delegate callback).

I have set a `QTCompressionOptions` object on the output specifying H264 Video and High Quality AAC Audio compression.

Each time I receive a call back, I append the data from the sample buffer into an `NSMutableData` object I have as an instance variable.

The problem I have is that no 'player' object in the QTKit framework seems capable of playing a 'stream' of video data. Am I correct in this assumption?

I tried creating a `QTMovie` object (to play in a `QTMovieView`) using my data instance variable but I get the error that the data is not a movie.

Am I approaching this issue from the wrong angle?

Previously I was using a `QTCapturePreviewOutput` which passes `CVImageBufferRef`s for each video frame. I was converting these frames into `NSImages` to display on a view.
While this gave the impression of streaming, it was slow and processor hungry.

How have other people conquered the streaming video problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you'd need to make a GL texture and then load the data into it on a per-frame basis. Everything about QTMovie seems to be based on pre-existing files, as far as my little mind can tell.